# How to create a dynamic request body based on header variables in CSV

Tags: jmeter

We have 100+ payloads request to test the IBM MQ in JMeter. Each payload request has dynamic RFH2 header values which we keep in separate files. Is it possible to create a single script which can create n numbers of parameters in request body based on the CSV files. I am using JSR223 sampler to send my payload request.

Request 1 Ex :
Values: "Test = Sample"
Request body: `rfh.setFieldValue('usr', 'Test', 'Sample')`

Request 2 Ex:
Values: Script = JMeter, ID= 10
Request body: `rfh.setFieldValue('usr', 'Script', 'JMeter')`
Request body: `rfh.setFieldValue('usr', 'ID', '10')`

May i know how can i create dynamic request body in JMeter based on available header values in each request.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the desired header names/values in the CSV file you can read them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

[image]

In the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) you can access the variables using [**vars** shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) like:

```
rfh.setFieldValue('usr', vars.get('name'), vars.get('value'))
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, thanks for your answer. My problem here is each payload will have multiple header values associated to it. for ex: 1st request will have two set of header values and 2nd request will have 10 set of header values. Here, how can i re-create this request dynamically for n number of times.
ex: 2 set of headers values then i need to pass this line(rfh.setFieldValue) two times to place the value.